# qtpropertybrowser height of a single line changeable?

Tags: qt

I'm working with qtpropertybrowser right now and I want to expend this with a new ability. When I click on the editor, it shows me a QLabel and a QToolButton, with the button I can choose a imagefile, the filename will be shown on the QLabel. When I left editor, it shows me the image.  I wrote my own manager and editorfactory, all is working.  But it shows me the image only in size of an icon ( I used the valueIcon methode for this). Is there a way to change the height of the line so the image shown is bigger?

Comment: Found the answer in the qttreepropertybrowser where I can define the size of the Icon.  It looks terrible though with the different line height. So I decided just to use a small version of the image as tooltip instead of a string.  It works fine.